# Salida inesperada al sumar todos los elementos de dos Arrays

Tags: java

Tengo una clase **Ejercicio** donde dentro tengo un método `main` y un método `getSuma` que devuelve un `int []`.

En el `main` he declarado dos `arrays`. Ambos arrays tienen la misma longitud a si que para ello he realizado un `for` tanto para inicializar las posiciones de ambos, como para realizar las sumas entre si.

He declarado dentro del método `getSuma` un `array` con una sola posición donde quiero sacar la suma total de todas las posiciones de ambos `arrays`.

Pero la salida no es la deseada.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Ejercicio8 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);

        System.out.println("Dime una longitud");
        int longitud = sc.nextInt();

        int elementoA [] = new int [longitud];//Array A
        int elementoB [] = new int [longitud];//Array B

        for(int i=0; i<elementoA.length; i++) {

            System.out.println("Dime un valor para A");
            elementoA[i] =sc.nextInt();

            System.out.println("Dime un valor para B");
            elementoB[i] =sc.nextInt();

        }


        System.out.println(Ejercicio8.getSuma(elementoA, elementoB));


    }

    public static int [] getSuma(int elementoA[] , int elementoB[]) {

        int solucion [] = new int [1]; //Array donde se almacena la suma

        for(int i=0; i<elementoA.length; i++) { //Bucle que realiza la suma

        solucion [0] = solucion [0] + elementoA[i] + elementoB[i];  

        }

        return solucion;

    }

}
```

**Salida inesperada**

```
[I@7d4991ad
```

Comment: podrias intentar con System.out.println(Ejercicio8.getSuma(elementoA, elementoB)[0]);

Answer (score 4):

El error que tienes es como devuelves el vector. Al hacer return solución, estas devolviendo la referencia a este vector. Debes decir que posición quieres devolver `solucion[0]`.

---

Extra comentarios

Tu quieres devolver una suma, en la variable solución. Para ello no hace falta que crees un vector de enteros, puedes usar la variable `int`.
Por otro lado, el metodo getSuma() ya existe dentro de esta clase. Por lo que directamente puedes llamar a `getSuma()`.

También sería recomendable hacer un `try catch` para comprobar si el valor es un entero.

Con estos comentarios el código quedaría así:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Ejercicio8 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);

        System.out.println("Dime una longitud");
        int longitud = sc.nextInt();

        int elementoA [] = new int [longitud];//Array A
        int elementoB [] = new int [longitud];//Array B

        for(int i=0; i<elementoA.length; i++) {

            System.out.println("Dime un valor para A");
            elementoA[i] =sc.nextInt();
            System.out.println(elementoA[i]);

            System.out.println("Dime un valor para B");
            elementoB[i] =sc.nextInt();

        }


        System.out.println(getSuma(elementoA, elementoB));
}


    public static int getSuma(int[] elementoA, int[] elementoB) {

        int solucion = 0; 

        for(int i=0; i<elementoA.length; i++) { //Bucle que realiza la suma

        solucion = solucion + elementoA[i] + elementoB[i];  

        }

        return solucion;

    }

}
```

Comment: Sin un array lo he logrado, pero el objetivo de este ejercicio es devolver la solución en un int []. Pero muchas gracias de todos modos.

Comment: @TALBARA si te ha servido la solución, debes marcarla con el tick verde que aparece a su lado, para ayudar a futuras personas que lleguen a esta pregunta con el mismo problema.

Answer (score 1):

Si quieres obtener el valor de la suma utilizando ese vector, en donde llamas a la función debes especificar la posición del elemento que tiene el resultado. En este caso, como el vector solo tiene 1 espacio, por decirlo así, la llamada a la función sería:

```
 System.out.println(Ejercicio8.getSuma(elementoA, elementoB)[0]);
```

Como estás recibiendo un array, especificas cual es el valor de la posición que quieres mostrar; 0 porque es el primer y único elemento. Así como tienes esa línea de codigo, estas mostrando la referencia a todo el vector.